# If an edit was suggested to an answer to my question and I go to this edit, I see the checkmark

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

For example, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32405) edit was proposed to an answer to my question. The bug is I see the checkmark when I go to this edit (I can't click checkmark however).

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (build rev `2015.2.23.3113` on meta, `2015.2.23.2333` on sites).

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't only apply to suggested edits. I also ran into this yesterday in the Very Low Quality queue.

[image: Checkmark shown in VLQQ answer]

Here too, i can't click it.

Comment: Can you plz start a bounty on it, I don't have enough rep...

Comment: a) You don't need 500 point bounties every time. b) Posting an answer also serves for bumping it. c) I have a hard time earning meta-rep; i don't want to just blow it here.

Comment: I already started a bounty earlier (300rep), so now I really don't have enough rep. But am I making you to do it? No. And, just curious, why do you need meta rep? ;)

Comment: You're not making me; i was just explaining why i won't. And meta rep unlocks meta privileges.

Comment: "And meta rep unlocks meta privileges" - But why do you want meta privileges?

Comment: Well, rep also makes that number by my name go up...

Comment: @nicael See, just posting an answer bumped it to their attention. :)